# How I can get the value from [value] or [ngvalue] in onInite angular 5?

Tags: angular

I have a small question, about the following:

I have a dropdown selector:

```
<select class="col-sm-2 form-control-static" [ngModel]="selectedLocation"  (ngModelChange)="onChangeObj($event)" >
     <option value="null" i18n="@@lnkAllLocation.label">All locations</option>
     <option [ngValue]="value" *ngFor="let value of values|slice:0:end" >{{value}}</option>
  </select>
```

so I have the value for all locations null, I did something like this to get this option, but I feel it is not efficient, and I cannot use all locations because I have a translation for it, so it changes.

```
onChangeObj(e: string) {
const isAllLocation = !this.values.find(element => element === e);
if (isAllLocation) {
  this.store$.dispatch(new SearchActions.Search({query: {'locations': []}}));
  Cookie.remove('SELECTED_LOCATION_VALUE', '/');
} else {
  this.store$.dispatch(new SearchActions.Search({query: {'locations': [e]}}));
  Cookie.save( 'SELECTED_LOCATION_VALUE', e, this.cookieSavedDays, '/');
}
```